# iphone 2d drawing newbie question

Tags: iphone, drawing, path, calayer, quartz-2d

I've been programming the iphone for a couple of months now and have 3 apps in the store already.

However, I have not done any kind of graphics programming in the platform.

Given that I'm planning on starting my 5th app (the 4th is under Apple's review) I wanted to ask for some pointers as to where to get information for this (been googling for a while but nothing matches what I'm looking for)

I need to create an App where I can 'drop' some shapes from a menu (a rectangle, circle, squares, and then some complex shapes) onto a main window.

the idea is that the user can drag them around. BUT, I want them to 'snap' to each other (kind of like in a CAD package where a circle has quadrants on the edges that snap to any other geometry entity in the drawing).

So if I had a circle on the left of the screen and a rectangle on the right and then I move the circle around, it would stop moving to the right If I hit the rectangles edges. Not completely stop but giving some sort of 'resistance' to the continuity of the movement.

Also, if I have several overlapping drawings, is there a way to 'divide' them (any overlapping becomes a shape on itself but is removed from any other shape composing the overlap)?

The reason for this is that I need to calculate the area of the drawing (along with other properties)

I'm thinking of CALayer 1, 2, 3,..., n on of top of the other, each one with a drawing (with CGPath?), that may or may not overlap the others.

Then I need to somehow obtain information of the 'projection' of all those on a single CALayer.

I'm clueless here.

Should I look into Quartz2D? is CALayer and CGPath enough for this?

this is not for a game. Just an engineering application I have in mind.

Any help is appreciated.

regards
dh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone Application Programming Guide has a chapter on [drawing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/GraphicsandDrawing/GraphicsandDrawing.html).

You might get some ideas where to start by looking at the appropriate lectures from [iPhone Application Programming](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php) lectures at Stanford. They include hight quality video lectures (filmed by Apple) over at iTunesU, slides and example source code.

Comment: I went through it before posting, but being new to drawing I still don't know if using Quartz is the proper approach, or even something like cocos-2d (even thought it's not a game). Also it does not give me an idea on how to get the total projection area.

But thanks for the reply, i'll wait and see if someone else can throw a hint